# MVC where can I find the error information after catching exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

Where to find the file that log.info is writing to in the MVC application.  I would like to look at the errors, but I cannot find where it is saving the errors to.

```
private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TermsController));

try { 

// some code to test

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
log.Info (ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on how you [`configured Log4Net`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15923/Configure-Log4Net-in-ASP-NET-2-0). If you haven't configured it, it won't write anywhere.

So basically in your web.config you could have a `log4net` section registered:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
```

which might look like this:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="c:\\Logs\\Log4Net.log"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>    
</log4net>
```

and then in your `Application_Start` you must have called:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

and the logs will be written to the `c:\logs\log4net.log` file.